# Membership.GetUser() C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I am trying to use either the UserName or (preferably) the user ID to determine what specific user is logged into my application.  My intent, is to limit the amount of content that can be uploaded to my site based on the user. Whenever the user attempts to upload a document, I want to retrieve a count of all the documents they have currently uploaded.  As a test run, I just added a label to my form to try and identify the user before writing a query:

```
// validate user. If they are not authenticated, do not let them upload files
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    uploadLabel.Visible = false;
    user.Text = Membership.GetUser().UserName; // this line should output the username
    mapUpload.Visible = false;
    uploadButton.Visible = false;
}
```

I know the authentication logic works, because all other fields are not visible when logged in.  Additionally, Membership.GetUser().UserName only has a value when the user IsAuthenticated; else, I get a null pointer exception. If the code is called, then Membership.GetUser().UserName appears to be setting the label to an empty text string.

Is there another way to get information for the current logged in user? As mentioned, my ultimate goal is be able to write a query with the information:

```
SELECT COUNT(DocumentID) FROM Documents WHERE UserID=@UserID
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Bic

Comment: Try this string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name;

Comment: The answers provided work. It turns out, it was a logic flaw.  The segment of code was only getting called when I was not logged in as an Admin. Since I kept logging in as an Admin, I was not hitting the || clause of the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use ***`MembershipUser`*** event to get currently logged in user we have another simple way to get currently logged in ***`username`*** you just define like this in your page

```
string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you replace

`user.Text = Membership.GetUser().UserName;`

with

`user.Text= User.Identity.Name`